# Conflict revtex4-2 class and nameref package

Tags: hyperref, revtex, nameref

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

Produces the following warning:

```
Package nameref Warning: The definition of \label has changed! Check your packages! Replacing it with the kernel definition on input line 145.
```

Can someone explain to me what the problem is and how I can get revtex working with hyperref without this warning? Maybe it's already well known, then just pointing me to a solution would be fine too, couldn't finde one.

Comment: I am not receiving any warnings in TexLive 2022.

Comment: @JohnSmith Then I will immediately try to update my TeXStudio and MikTeX. Thanks for testing. Add: I got this warning on Overleaf too btw.

Comment: @JohnSmith I still get the error. I use TeXStudio 4.6.3, have updated all MikTeX packages now too. Furthermore on Overleaf the exact same thing happens. (E.g. for those who can access it: https://www.overleaf.com/6795341177bpxyndcbphsd#9bc51f )

Comment: That is not an error. Only a warning and it should be harmless.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I hate warnings, but if you say it's harmless I can live with that. Just wanted to make sure, since it freaked me out a little when I first tried out revtex today and I already get a warning when I haven't even done anything significiant ^^. Thanks Ulrike. (You may close this question.)

Comment: Complain to the revtex maintainer. If they stop to redefine needlessly label the warning would go away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

revtex redefines the `\label` command. In a current LaTeX kernel, `\label` is defined like this:

```
\def\label#1{\@bsphack
  \begingroup
  \UseHookWithArguments{label}{1}{#1}%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}%
          {\@currentlabelname}{\@currentHref}{\@kernel@reserved@label@data}}}%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack}
```

After revtex the definition is:

```
\def\label#1{%
 \@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
   \string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}{}{}{}}%
  }%
 \@esphack
}%
```

That means the hook is missing and the label doesn't store `\@currentlabelname` and `\@currentHref`. `nameref` (and hyperref too) needs the new enhanced `\label` and so checks the `label` definition and warns if it detects that is a wrong one and reinstates the kernel version. To get rid of the warning you should try to convince the revtex maintainer to remove their redefinition (which is quite unneeded in a current LaTeX).